# MySQL Create Table Statements not being replicated

Tags: mysql, sql, database-replication

I have a one master 5 slave MySQL replication setup. When I create a table on my master, it gets replicated on 3 of the 5 slaves. The other slaves however do not replicate the "CREATE TABLE" transaction.

All operations including DROP on existing tables get replicated all across.

The following is the output of my SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G; command on a perfectly working slave.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: X.X.X.X
              Master_User: slave22
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003852
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 822377736
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.001788
            Relay_Log_Pos: 822377881
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003852
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 822377736
          Relay_Log_Space: 822378080
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error: 
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:
```

Now Here is the output of SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G command on a slave that is not replicating the CREATE STATEMENTS

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: X.X.X.X
              Master_User: slave21
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003852
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 822708979
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.001793
            Relay_Log_Pos: 822709124
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003852
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 822708979
          Relay_Log_Space: 822709323
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error: 
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:
```

Please advise